# Does window with 64bit can run tomcat 7.0.52 as a service with service.bat?

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7

I would like to know if machines with 64 bits can run tomcat 7.0.52 as a service with service.bat or they must use service-64.bat for that matters

Hope it's clear enough

Nir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use service.bat with 64-bit windows to install Tomcat as a service. There is no such file as service-64.bat.